# Не работает отправка текста из textarea

Tags: ajax, javascript, tinymce

На сайте установил TinyMCE и ajaxForm и в связи с этим не работает отправка текста из textarea. В чем проблема, можно ли как-то решить? Когда аяксформ отключаю, то все норм.

Comment: Тестовый архив есть? И дей-но логи

Comment: А атрибут name этого textarea верно передается в $_POST?

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE имеет два режима: `textarea` (когда показывает код) и `iframe` (визуальный режим). Скорее всего ты пытаешься отправить из второго режима.